# Uninstall and reinstall ROS

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I wanted to remove my ROS fuerte and reinstall it due to some error I can't solve even with solution. So I wanna ask whether can I remove current ROS and reinstall it later on? Will my package still remain or I need to create them all over again after that? How am I suppose to do?

Here's the error wish someone could have help me so I don't need to remove my ROS.

http://answers.ros.org/question/86126/import-errorno-module-named-rospkg/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86766/uninstall-and-reinstall-ros/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-03**:
What do you mean with 'Will my package still remain'?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-03**:
All those package that I created in my workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you created your workspace properly, you should be fine. The only thing the workspace does is sourcing /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash this happens in ~/yourworkspace/setup.bash. So if ROS is reinstalled at the same place there should be no problem I think.

To uninstall ROS completely (debian packages and their configs) do:

```
sudo apt-get purge ros-fuerte-*
```

To reinstall simply follow the instructions from the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-03**:
So after I delete my ROS and reinstall, I dont need to reconfigure anything about my workspace and all those packages right?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-03**:
I think so. Nevertheless I recommend a backup of your machine. You never know...

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-03**:
Yea I was thinking backing up my workspace and then after reinstall just rosmake them. What do you suggest?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-03**:
I think that should work.